# How to change the page layout in Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to change my category page layout to `2columns-left.phtml`. The default is a 3 column layout. I only want to set the category page layout to `2columns-left.phtml`. The rest should keep the default page layout (3 columns). How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this for categories individually under the Design tab. You can do this for all categories by adding a `local.xml` to your custom theme's `layout` folder which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

    <my_category_root_template>
        <reference name="root">
            <tpl>page/2columns-left.phtml</tpl>
        </reference>
    <my_category_root_template>

    <catalog_category_layered>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_default>

    <!-- EDIT: forgot about search results page -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<layout>
```

For further info, [Magebase has a great Layout XML primer](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/), and [Alan Storm wrote the book on it](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout).

Comment: how to name this <my_category_root_template>

Comment: if i want to alter the original xml file, which file should i do?

Comment: The name "my_category_root_template" is arbitrary - it just needs to be unique. You are adding its instructions to the other layout update handles below. As far as altering the original, you would need to copy catalog.xml to your custom theme and edit it there - but that means you "own" all of the other *unchanged* layout update directives. That's one of the main intention uses for local.xml - making discreet changes without needing to merge unchanged content in a software update.

Comment: Note that I forgot the search results page; added that page's handle.

Comment: This only worked for me when I changed the first block to: `<my_category_root_template>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_category_root_template>` ...otherwise works great though

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with magneto but i think it may work.

Go to admin->Catalog->Categories->Manage Categories

Then go to ->Custom Design

You will find *Page Layout* option there change that to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

First to set up the categories: in the admin panel, select the Catalog menu.  Then on the left, select the category that you wish to edit.  On the right, the Custom Design tab contains the Page Layout property.  If you want all categories to have the same layout, set the root category's Page Layout accordingly, and then the child categories' "Use Parent Category Settings" property to True.

The layout for all other pages will be determined by the CMS->Pages page.  Click the page to modify, then on the left, select Design, and then on the right, the Layout property.

If you are wondering how to make sure that all subsequently created pages in the CMS admin area by default use a particular layout, so that you don't have to change it each time you create a new content page, I am not certain, as mine seems to default to 1column, even though the XML seems to configure the  page to use 3-column (I'm referring to what is in /app/design/frontend///layout/page.xml)..  I may misunderstand how that is linked to this, though, perhaps someone else can comment.  My understanding is that the CMS pages have their layout settings and custom layout information stored in the database.  Therefore, perhaps there is another setting in the database that choose the default when creating a new CMS page.

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like Ben got you covered :)